# java ServerSocket does not throw IOException when bind to the same port

Tags: java, sockets

I have an issue with my code as follow.
code:

```
int port = 14205; // begin port
// Try to bind socket on any port<br>

while(true){

try {
     InetSocketAddress isa = new InetSocketAddress(port);
    Log.logFile("bind port = " + port);

        // ss is a ServerSocket object
    ss.bind( isa );

    break;
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.logFile("exception");
    port++;
}
 }
```

I ran this code on JVM 1.7 and JVM 1.6 at the same time on the same machine (win7x64). using CurrPorts tool to investigate what port we are listening.
result: we'are listening on the same port 14207.
I think JVM must throw an IOException when run 2nd instance of this code but it didn't.

what wrong with my code?
please help.
note: I must run in this senario (2 JVMs).

Comment: You have exactly one `ss` (I'm assuming that's `ServerSocket`) and you `break` out of the loop after binding it. I'm failing to see why you think that wouldn't work.

Comment: Please show how you're creating and setting up `ss`. If you mean you're executing two separate instances of this program concurrently I have a sneaking suspicion this isn't TCP.

Comment: hi Brian! ServerSocket ss=null; <br>
ServerSocketChannel ssc = null;
     
try{
    // Create a Server Socket Channel
    ssc = ServerSocketChannel.open();
    // Set it to non-blocking, so we can use select
    ssc.configureBlocking(false);
   
    //Get the Socket connected to this channel, and bind it
    // to the listening port
    ss = ssc.socket();

Answer (score 1):

`break;` will break your while loop and exit from the while loop and no question about catching `exception`. However, When your are trying to catch the exception you need to print exception message to log file.

replace this

```
Log.logFile("exception");
```

with this

```
Log.logFile("exception"+ e.toString());
```

Comment: There's no reason it would ever throw an exception; notice the `break` statement. (I didn't downvote you but ... this really isn't an answer to his question; it will log what he told it to log if there was an exception).

Answer (score 1):

Your loop breaks after binding first time.

Comment: @Brian Roach: your comment is what I mean. in addition, no matter how I logged. when the first instance run, everything must be OK, right? and a port (for ex: 14027 will be used by this process). but when I run the second instance on other JVM, we can not use port 14027 anymore, and must throw exception when port variable reach to 14027. after all, in second instance, it must use port number that is larger than 14027.

Answer (score 0):

ok! I will answer my question.
this is JVM bug. for more information please refer to Oracle bugbase:
https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug;jsessionid=71f70e71266a551ce53dcda4a050c?bug_id=7174699